# What is the problem with my show function in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I got the following error:

> ErrorException Undefined variable: products (View:
> C:\xampp\htdocs\bizzcomputer\resources\views\user\show.blade.php)

Other than show function everything works fine.
Why I am getting this error? Can anyone give a hand to sort out it?

This is the code from

ProductsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;
use App\Category;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $product = Product::find($id);
        return view('user.show', ['product' => $product]);
    }
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/admin/index', 'ProductsController@index')->name('list_products');
Route::get('/admin', 'HomeController@test')->name('admin');
Route::resource('/admin/products', 'Admin\ProductsController', ['as'=>'admin']);
Route::get('/user/{product}','Admin\ProductsController@show');
```

show.blade.php

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    <a href="../shop/product-categories-7-column-full-width.html" class="d-block py-2 text-center">
        <img class="img-fluid mb-1 max-width-100-sm" src="{{ asset('assets/img/300X300/img6.jpg')}}" alt="Image Description">
        <h6 class="font-size-14 mb-0 atext font-weight-semi-bold">{{ $product -> prod_name }}</h6>
    </a>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing a variable to the view named `products`:

```
return view ('user.show', ['product' => $product]);
```

No variable named `products`.

Your view is trying to use `$products` in the `foreach` loop.

Your `show` method is for showing a single product so there won't be anything to loop over, as you will only have a single product to display.

Answer (score 0):

In your show blade you're expecting `products` whereas in your controller in show method, you're sending one instance of `product`.

Your controller is fine, and exactly how it should be. You need to make changes in your blade.

Now that in your blade you're receiving one product only. Remove the loop, and show the product details.

```
<a href="../shop/product-categories-7-column-full-width.html" class="d-block py-2 text-center">
            <img class="img-fluid mb-1 max-width-100-sm" src="{{ asset('assets/img/300X300/img6.jpg')}}" alt="Image Description">
                 <h6 class="font-size-14 mb-0 atext font-weight-semi-bold">{{ $product -> prod_name }}</h6>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your controller you give product variable, not products. Inside your view you are trying to get products variable. Just change your controller action to:

```
public function show($id)
{
   $product = Product::find($id);
    return view ('user.show',['products'=>$product]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your *show()* method you are getting single product and sending variable *$product* to view .

```
public function show($id)
    {
       $product = Product::find($id);
       return view ('user.show',['product'=>$product]);
    }
```

But you are trying to access *$products* variable using foreach loop that is not possible. as you are getting single product and passing to view so you should use below example for accessing properties *$product*'s   object

```
 $product->name
$product->price
$product->category_name
```

etc.